# logstash - Parse numbers from and convert Storage units in logs using Ruby FIlter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Extract the NUMBER from logs and convert storage units.

Sample Logs -

2020-02-04 16:18:56,783 INFO Log4jFactory$Log4jLogger [10.xxx.xxx.xxx]:5701 [Dry-PROD-XC6] [3.7.6] Received auth from Connection[id=26876, /10.xxx.xxx.xxx:5701->/10.xxx.xxx.xxx:56584, endpoint=null, alive=true, type=CSHARP_CLIENT], successfully authenticated, principal : ClientPrincipal{uuid='d7d8b718-ed75-4cc3-b51a-c620bb082255', ownerUuid='058720ad-7b35-40f6-8978-bd9cf7e286ec'}, owner connection : true, client version : null

2020-02-04 16:15:27,519 INFO Log4jFactory$Log4jLogger [10.xxx.xxx.xxx]:5701 [Dry-PROD-XC6] [3.7.6] processors=8, physical.memory.total=31.4G, physical.memory.free=18.8G, swap.space.total=7.8G, swap.space.free=7.8G, heap.memory.used=4.5G, heap.memory.free=536.5M, heap.memory.total=5.0G, heap.memory.max=5.0G, heap.memory.used/total=89.51%, heap.memory.used/max=89.51%, native.memory.used=8.2M, native.memory.free=3.5G, native.memory.total=64.0M, native.memory.max=3.5G, native.meta.memory.used=80.0M, native.meta.memory.free=432.0M, native.meta.memory.percentage=90.75%, minor.gc.count=18605, minor.gc.time=121136ms, major.gc.count=0, major.gc.time=0ms, load.process=0.00%, load.system=0.01%, load.systemAverage=1.00%, thread.count=69, thread.peakCount=229, cluster.timeDiff=4083, event.q.size=0, executor.q.async.size=0, executor.q.client.size=0, executor.q.query.size=0, executor.q.scheduled.size=0, executor.q.io.size=0, executor.q.system.size=0, executor.q.operations.size=0, executor.q.priorityOperation.size=0, operations.completed.count=351751533, executor.q.mapLoad.size=0, executor.q.mapLoadAllKeys.size=0, executor.q.cluster.size=0, executor.q.response.size=0, operations.running.count=0, operations.pending.invocations.percentage=0.00%, operations.pending.invocations.count=1, proxy.count=0, clientEndpoint.count=231, connection.active.count=232, client.connection.count=231, connection.count=1

Trying to extract the NUMBER for the Memory fields (like native.memory.used=8.2M, native.memory.free=3.5G, native.memory.total=64.0M, native.memory.max=3.5G) and convert units using Ruby Filter.

Used Logstash KV Filter first to obtain the KV pairs , then trying the following code (I'm new to Ruby Coding)

my Ruby Code -

```
               ruby {
                        code => '
                        event.to_hash.keys.each { |k,v|
                        matches = v.scan(/(\d*\.\d*?i)([KMG])$/)
                    if matches[2] == nil
                        event.set(k,event.get(v))
                    elsif matches[2] == "K"
                        multiplyBy = 1024
                        event.set(k, matches[1].to_f * multiplyBy)
                    elsif matches[2] == "M"
                        multiplyBy = 1024 * 1024
                        event.set(k, matches[1].to_f * multiplyBy)
                    elsif matches[2] == "G"
                        multiplyBy = 1024 * 1024 * 1024
                        event.set(k, matches[1].to_f * multiplyBy)
                    else
                        event.set(k, event.get(v))
                    end
                }
    '
}
```

Seeing Errors in the logs -

[2020-02-11T17:01:09,603][ERROR][logstash.filters.ruby    ][main] Ruby exception occurred: undefined method `scan' for nil:NilClass

appreciate any help or guidance .
Thank you

Comment: You could use the [kv filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html) to extract the numbers.

Comment: @baudsp - I already extracted the kv pairs, but the problem is I am unable to use the memory related fields ending with M|G for any visualizations in Kibana, because they're created as string fields.   I could use regex to just extract the values, but the unit in the value can change from M to G , which is making it difficult for use. I am trying ruby code, but haven't been successful soo far.

Answer (score 0):

[**Regex**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) would do the trick:

If you want to match the unit:

`\d*?\.\d*?(M|G)`

If you just want to match the number (integer or decimal):

`\d*?(\.)\d*`

`\d` stands for digits

`*` stands x times

`?` is used here to be non greedy (minimize the effort of the parser) after the * option (good practise)

`( | )` stands for OR and  set the option between 2 caracters M or G `(` this may vary depending on the language in which the parser is executed

If you have any doubt you can test the regular expresion [here](https://regex101.com/r/3B3Wmx/1).

You ca optimise your regex if you control the number of decimals using `{}` 
and add optional the `.` if you are not sure that you will have always decimals.

As far as I remember, you have option in logstash to parse using regex and output it properly using grok or a builtin filter and output it directly as you want it.

Comment: Thanks @c24b, actually was trying to do more than just extracting the fields. I wanted to convert them to bytes, because the units (M|G) can change.   I was thinking more on the ruby code to achieve this

Comment: In this case you should change the title to say that you  convert units this can be achived quite simpy in any programming language just split your results in two and apply the operation convert2bytes(float, unit)

Comment: I tried using ruby filter to add some code, but it did not help .. Errors in the logstash logs ..

Comment: You have to get out from the logstash context to process this conversion I suppose: means handle errors, bad formatting and rewrite log with ruby